# data duplicating when use custom controller in laravel's voyager admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I use laravel 5.4 and [voyager admin panel](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager). There's module I created called recipes. I created database table, model and CUSTOM controller and views for this module. I also created BREAD, and indicated there my custom controller. the problem is the when I fill form and submit it, data been duplicated in table, I have 2 identical rows in my table every time I create the item. I think the problem is that it sends 2 requests, one of requests is from my custom route and controller, and another one is from voyager itself. but don't know how to fix it.

print screen from my BREAD
[image: BREAD's printscreen]

my routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['admin']], function () {

   \Voyager::routes(); //voyager routes

   // routes for my custom module
   // I can comment this routes, but result is the same
   Route::resource('/recipes', 'Admin\RecipesController');

});
```

my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $recipe = Recipe::create($request->except(['modules']));
    return redirect()
        ->route("recipes.index")
        ->with([
            'message'    => __('voyager.generic.successfully_added_new')." recipe",
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ]);
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was because of `form` element class `form-edit-add`, as it seems there was event bound to this class. I removed it and now it works fine

Answer (score 2):

You should try this for check `AJax Request`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) {
        $recipe = Recipe::create($request->except(['modules']));

    }
    return redirect()
            ->route("recipes.index")
            ->with([
                'message'    => __('voyager.generic.successfully_added_new')." recipe",
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            ]);
}
```